# Gang of Four - definition help!

Tags: java, design-patterns, definition

I've got a question about the following terms..what do they mean in terms of a strategy pattern?

Algorithm Interface

Context Interface

Class Strategy

Class Context

Attribute Strategy

Concrete Strategy

And their hierarchy...

In other words, what would be their places in a normal strategy pattern?

-D

Comment: SO is not a substitute for Google.

Comment: not homework, i just cant find a place that easily defines these terms

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: -1 Lazy question. In time it took the write the question you could have found the answer yourself.

Comment: -1 If this isn't homework, I'll eat my shoe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In very simple words ( and just to provide some context )

*Algorithm Interface* The methods the algorithm ( strategy ) will have.

*Context Interface* The methods exposed by the main object to which an strategy will be added to.

*Class Strategy* The class implementing/defining the strategy.

*Class Context* The class that will use the strategy.

*Attribute Strategy* The attribute of the context class that will be the strategy.

*Concrete Strategy* A concrete implementation of the strategy class/interface.

*And their hierarchy* ¬¬